# Fluent nhibernate how to generate Unique id

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am sorry for simplest question but I want to now if is any way to generate id column on each table to be like 1,2,3,4,... n.
Now I have following :

```
 Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

For each table this will generate Id from 1 to n , on each table will start again from one  but I need Id column to be unique in all my  database.To start from one and continue to N.How  I can  achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You have two ways:

**1.** Create a unique Sequence in your database and map like this:

```
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native("YOURSEQUENCE_SEQ");
```

**2.** Use a NHibernate HiLo to control your ids (its the better approach) read more in this link:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2010/10/using-hilo-with-fluentnhibernate/

Comment: Ok I will try to find out , but I was expecting that should be something more easy than this ...Thanks

Comment: I know of no other way to do this. I believe they are the only ones.